# How to bring back formatting as well as data in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that contains many worksheets (1 project outline per page) and want to summarise the project by bringing back only select cells from each worksheet.  This is for a progress report, where only the data from a number of cells from each worksheet are required (ie those that change such as progress, cost to date, last week and next week works).

I can see that Excel can bring back cells and keep line breaks, but not formatting within the cell (eg Bold, text size, etc).  Is there a method to bring the formatting over also via a formula automatically?  With reference to the image below, any updates (content and formatting) in B4 would be replicated in C4.  I note with word wrap I can being back the line breaks only.

[image]

Comment: What I use is Paste Special:  Values and Source Formatting

Comment: No, the formatting you are referring to is a hack that only works because there are no formulas in the source cells.

Comment: Thanks John, this seems to work for formatting of the cell, but not the formatting within the cell (eg the bold Heading Line 4).

Comment: The result of a formula can only have the formatting of the cell

Comment: Keep source formatting?